# Change image of character when travelled specific number of pixels

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame. I want to change the image of the character whenever it moves a certain amount of pixels to make it seem like he's walking, but I can't really understand how to do that. Here's the code:

```py
import pygame
import time
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREY = (129, 129, 129)
frame = 0

class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, colour):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.set_colorkey(colour)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x =0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Untitled.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 2, 48, 48, WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def move(self, y):
        self.rect.y += y
        if self.rect.y == 400:
            self.kill()

class Soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.direction = "R"
        super().__init__()
        self.walking_frames_l = []
        self.walking_frames_r = []
        
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Picture2.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 150, 205, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)

        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(233, 0, 140, 210, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(425, 5, 123, 210, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)

        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 150, 205, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(233, 0, 140, 210, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(425, 5, 123, 210, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)

        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[0]
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 297
        self.rect.x = 100


    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
    def walk(self):
        global frame
        if self.change_x > 0:
            frame +=1
            time.sleep(.1)
        if frame == 3:
            frame = 0
        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[frame]

    def go_left(self):
        self.change_x = -6
 
    def go_right(self):
        self.change_x = 6
    def stop(self):
        self.change_x = 0
        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[2]
pygame.init()
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
bomb  = Bomb()
soldier = Soldier()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(bomb)
all_sprites.add(soldier)
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    soldier.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    soldier.go_right()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and soldier.change_x < 0:
                soldier.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and soldier.change_x > 0:
                soldier.stop()
    
    screen.fill(RED)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    bomb.move(2)
    soldier.move()
    soldier.walk()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

I also tried to change the image after a particular amount of time (This part):

```
    def walk(self):
        global frame
        if self.change_x > 0:
            frame +=1
            time.sleep(.1)
        if frame == 3:
            frame = 0
        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[frame]
```

When I add time.sleep(.1) and try to move the character, it somehow affects the bomb. It moves 2 pixels, waits for .1 seconds and again moves 2 pixels.

Is there any way I can do either of the things mentioned above (either change the image after a particular amount of time or after a specific amount of pixels travelled)?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frame` has to be an attribute of the `Soldier` class. Additionally you need an `attribute` for the number of pixels the player has moved:

```py
class Soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.frame = 0
        self.moved = 0
```

Add the absolute movement to `self.moved`. Increment `frame` when the movement exceeds a certain number of pixels (`pixel_for_one_step` ):

```py
class Soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def walk(self):
        self.moved += abs(self.change_x)

        pixels_for_one_step = 60
        if self.moved > pixels_for_one_step:
            self.moved -= pixels_for_one_step
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame >= len(self.walking_frames_r):
                self.frame = 0

        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[self.frame]
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREY = (129, 129, 129)

class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height, colour):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.set_colorkey(colour)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x =0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Untitled.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(2, 2, 48, 48, WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def move(self, y):
        self.rect.y += y
        if self.rect.y == 400:
            self.kill()

class Soldier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.direction = "R"
        super().__init__()
        self.walking_frames_l = []
        self.walking_frames_r = []
        
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Picture2.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 150, 205, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)

        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(233, 0, 140, 210, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(425, 5, 123, 210, GREY)
        self.walking_frames_l.append(self.image)

        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 150, 205, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(233, 0, 140, 210, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(425, 5, 123, 210, GREY)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(self.image)

        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[0]
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 297
        self.rect.x = 100
        self.frame = 0
        self.moved = 0


    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
    def walk(self):
        self.moved += abs(self.change_x)

        pixels_for_one_step = 60
        if self.moved > pixels_for_one_step:
            self.moved -= pixels_for_one_step
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame >= len(self.walking_frames_r):
                self.frame = 0

        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[self.frame]

    def go_left(self):
        self.change_x = -6
 
    def go_right(self):
        self.change_x = 6
    def stop(self):
        self.change_x = 0
        self.image = self.walking_frames_r[2]
pygame.init()
screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
bomb  = Bomb()
soldier = Soldier()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(bomb)
all_sprites.add(soldier)
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    soldier.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    soldier.go_right()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and soldier.change_x < 0:
                soldier.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and soldier.change_x > 0:
                soldier.stop()
    
    screen.fill(RED)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    bomb.move(2)
    soldier.move()
    soldier.walk()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @PianoPianist I've fixed the syntax errors, but It works fine for me. You just failed to apply it to your code. *"What I mean is, as long as it is moving, or the right key is pressed, it should change the image."* - Yes, this is exactly what my code is doing. I've added the complete example code to the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the right key part, I forgot to write self. before frame  Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you very much!! You have helped me a lot!

Comment: Just one thing I'd like to point out, your code changes the costumes 60 times per second, I changed it a bit and it did the trick for me :D **def walk(self):
        self.moved += abs(self.change_x)
        if self.change_x == 0:
            self.moved = 0
        pixels_for_one_step = 60
        if self.moved > pixels_for_one_step:
            self.frame += 1
            self.moved = 0
            if self.frame >= len(self.walking_frames_r):
                self.frame = 0**            And you forgot to add super().__init__() . Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: @PianoPianist Yes of course. You can adjust the time for a frame with the value of `pixels_for_one_step`. The 12 in my code was just a guess (I didn't know how big your sprites are).

Comment: Sorry, I thought something was wrong with the code, I didn't realize it was just because of the 12. Thank you so much once again!